# Do fleets count for the Mobilization boost?

Tags: civilization-6

Do fleets count towards the "Have 3 Corps in your military" requirement to boost Mobilization?

Answer (score 2):

No, I tested with two corps (Musketmen and Field Cannons) and a submarine fleet and it did not trigger the Eureka for the Mobilization civic.

[image]

Comment: It makes sense because they're labeled different things.

Comment: Yeah, but for the sake of brevity it's plausible it may have been shortened from "Corps or Armies or Fleets or Flotillas"